# Why background thread not exiting when form closes?

Tags: c#, multithreading

As I understand it, if I set `_myThread.isBackground = true` then the thread should exit when the form is closed.  Unfortunately I'm not finding that my thread is exiting.  Here is what my code looks like:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // <snip>
    daemon = new Daemon();
    // <snip>
}

public Daemon()
{
    // Start the main thread which will do most of the connection checking and work
    _mainThread = new Thread(() => MainThread(this));
    _mainThread.IsBackground = true;
    _mainThread.Start();
}

/// <summary>
/// This is the work that the main thread does.
/// </summary>
private void MainThread(Daemon daemon)
{
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            // Do things.
            Thread.Sleep(2000);            // Sleep for a bit to not hammer.
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Exception(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I thought that since the thread is started from the form that setting `isBackground=true` would force it to close on form exit.

Am I missing or misinterpreting something?

Comment: Background threads are not stopped when you close a form, they are stopped when **all foreground threads** have terminated. So it seems to me that there is something that does not terminate (or prevents termination) of your foreground thread(s). Use the debugger in Visual Studio to see the state of all the threads when you close the form...

Comment: Your code as written is cleanly exiting on my machine (without a hanging background process). I suspect that you have another non-background thread that's keeping the clr from closing the application.

Comment: How this code proofs it does not end the background thread? Plus, how long it is running for after application closes?

Comment: If one of the given answers is the accepted answer for the question then you should accept it by clicking the hollow check mark next to the answer, so that it becomes green. If you found a different solution then you should describe it here and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking that the thread is a background thread *prevents it from keeping the process alive*.  The process will stick around for as long as there is at least one non-background thread running.  The UI thread is a non-background thread, and *by default* in a winform application closing the main thread will result in that thread completing.

So now that we have all of this we can see that, often enough, closing the main form will "kill" background processes, but there are any number of things that can stop this.

The main thread ending doesn't *necessarily* mean the application will end, and the UI thread will terminate.  One can adjust the behavior of the application to end under different criteria, or add code to run in `Main` after the application finishes running.

You can also create additional non-UI threads, and if you do, they'll keep the entire process (and all of the background threads) alive.

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) background thread just wont prevent the process from terminating. There is no guarantee that the thread will finish "nicely", whatever that may mean.

Comment: The documentation also says "*Any remaining background threads are stopped and do not complete.*" -- so background threads won't linger around any longer when all foreground threads have been terminated. (OP wondered why his background thread is *not* exiting...)

Comment: That's correct. I guess the answer to OPs question is "there's no misinterpretation, and you're missing something".

Answer (score 0):

IsBackground = true means that when main thread ended (and all other non-background threads) - it'll stop. But what are these threads ? I believe when you close your mainform you still have one non-background thread running may be one where this form was created and ititialized.

Comment: `IsBackground = true means that when main thread ended it'll stop` This is not quite true.  The correct statement is that the process terminates when there are no longer any non-background threads running.  Your statement is only true when the UI thread is the only non-background thread and where the UI is configured such that closing the main form stops the application.

Comment: You're right . I assumed that there are only two threads running at the time but if it's more- then yes, all non-background threads.